# Visual Studio 2017 error when creating or opening solution

Tags: visual-studio

Using Visual Studio Community 2017.

When creating or opening any solutions I get:

> Object of type 'System.Lazy'1[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SVsDebugTargetSelectionService] cannot be converted to type 'System.Lazy'1[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsProjectCfgDebugTypeSelection]'.

Tried an uninstall & reinstall with the same result. Any ideas?